# Giant Try Catch Block in Main

Tags: c++, exception, program-entry-point

I have a class that can throw an exception inside the constructor. I do not know own the code for this class so I cannot change this behavior or add other instantiation or initialization methods to this class. I need to create an object of this class inside of main. Does this mean that I need to have a main() that consists mostly of one giant try / catch block like this:

```
main()
{
  try
  {
    A a;
    ...
  }
  catch(std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

What if this main is thousands of lines long? This try / catch block is huge. I feel like there should be a better way of doing this but I cannot think of one.

Comment: "What if this main is thousands of lines long?"   That would be your problem, not the try/catch block.

Comment: Surround the code for this type that could fail (and is not preventable otherwise) with try/catch blocks, not the entire thing. You should not need to rely on a giant try/catch to handle any error that may happen in your project, this could catch unexpected exceptions as well.

Comment: [main() returns int]
try-catch block in main is a (near universal) common practice.
"...thousands of lines long... " is vicious.

Comment: Even if one is prone to making thousands of lines long functions, so what? Why does it matter if you have a huge try/catch block? It's not like it will require extra typing. Unless you type all your indentation manually.

Comment: The number of lines of code in main() has very little correspondence to the amount of code in your program.  You could just rename main() as something else, like main_inner(), and then call main_inner() from within a try block in main().

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I type everything manually. I use VIM for everything. I don't use a real IDE like Netbeans, Eclipse, etc. Just how I have always done things.

Comment: @TLytle: You don't need an IDE in order to do automatic indentation. Any decent text editor will do that for you. Usually by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What if this main is thousands of lines long?
>   ... I feel like there should be a better way of doing this but I cannot think of one.

That's clearly a sign for bad design and should be **refactored** into classes and function calls.

Ideally to something like this in `main()`:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    try {
        Application app(argc,argv);
        app.run();
    }
    catch(std::exception& e) {
         std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Still the

```
try {
    // Refactored 1000 lines of code
}
catch(std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

must enclose the calling code.

Comment: Ah. I see now. Encapsulating everything into a class that has a single entry point is what I need to do. Where you have Application::run(), I instead have about 1000 lines of conditional tests and function calls. But, putting it all into a "Application Manager" class that understand what needs to be done and how to do is what I was needing. This allows for a single function call and keeps the main() small and concise. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> Does this mean that I need to have a main() that consists mostly of one giant try / catch block

Yes.

> What if this main is thousands of lines long?

It shouldn't be. Make it not. Devolve your functionality into, well, *functions*!

And don't forget your return type for `main()` (which is `int`).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different ways you can handle this.

Put a [function-try-block](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block) around the body of `main()`:

```
int main() try
{
  A a;
  // use 'a' as needed ...
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
catch (const std::exception& e)
{
  std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Refactor the code to move the bulk of `main()` to another function that you can then call inside a `try/except` block:

```
void run()
{
  A a;
  // use 'a' as needed ...
}

int main()
{
  try
  {
    run();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
  catch (const std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
}
```

Personally, I would just instantiate the class on the heap instead of on the stack.  That way, you can put the `try/catch` around just the instantiation:

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<A> a; // or std::auto_ptr<A> prior to C++11...

  try
  {
    a.reset(new A);
    // or, in C++14 and later:
    // a = std::make_unique<A>();
  }
  catch(const std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  // use 'a' as needed ...

  // the A object is freed automatically when 'a' goes out of scope...

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no sensible way to handle the exception, then don't bother with a `try` block. Just let the exception escape and take down the program - the alternative is to continue while the "world" is not in a sane state - not a good idea.
Crashing when you have no sane way to handle an error is reasonable. Catching exceptions is something you should only do *if* you have a reasonable way to deal with them. By default, just let them propagate.

If you *can* handle the exception sensibly, add the `try` block just around the instantiation of the object and then do the sane error handling in the `catch` block